# useFetch to authenticate token

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a NUXT component that just needs to authenticate a users zendesk token, would the useFetch composable the correct way to do this?

I first gave this a go but looking to rewrite in the best way:

```
zE('messenger', 'loginUser', function (callback:any) {

  const url = query.data?.data.attributes?.token

  // Using ref to store the token
  const token = ref(null);

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      // Update the token using the callback
      token.value = json.token;
      callback(json.token);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching Zendesk token:', error))
})
```

Comment: what is best is up to you, since you understand your app and requirements better than anyone else.  when you read the [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) for useFetch, does it _sound_ like a better option than standard fetch?  is there some negative or downside to your current method that you think could be improved using an alternative method?